# Should I use a single DataGrid, multiple DataGrids or something entirely different?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a collection of objects we'll call People each comprised of Name, ID and Time strings.  These People must be displayed on a grid which resembles a fixed number of rows and 9 columns.  The idea is that People are added as rows to the left side of the grid in columns 1, 2 and 3.  Once the last row is filled, the subsequent row is added to the "top" of what is column group 4, 5 and 6 in a "wrapping" effect.  After that grouping fill up, the last group of 7, 8 and 9 is used.

I am trying to decide whether to use a single DataGrid to do this, or to use three separate ones.  The data will be updated every few seconds so performance is a concern.  However, my main concern is which approach will be easier and cleaner to implement.  Is there a third party grid control that has this "wrapping" functionality?

This is a C# application using WPF.

Thank you.

Comment: going with what @alain said, if the user is NOT entering data, don't use `DataGrid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use any kind of DataGrid at all, just a ListView with a [WrapPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx) content presenter and a well defined ItemsTemplate.

Here's a sample style to get you started:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
          <ScrollViewer Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <WrapPanel ItemWidth="150" IsItemsHost="True" MinWidth="100"
                       Width="{Binding ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}">
            </WrapPanel>
          </ScrollViewer>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Ok, after some tweaking of my own code this seemed to do the job.  I appreciate the help.  Saved me lots of time!